# How can I import Elastic-Net, Lasso and Ridge regression in Pyspark?

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, linear-regression, apache-spark-ml, lasso-regression

Could you please tell me how can I use `Elastic-Net`, Lasso and Ridge regression in Pyspark? Actually I chose Linear, Elastic-Net, Lasso and Ridge regression these 4 algorithms according to machine learning cheatsheet. However, I don't know how to import Elastic-Net, Lasso and Ridge regression in Pyspark and cannot google the right answers. I just know using the Linear Regression in `Pyspark`.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/ml-linear-methods.html

You can use something like:

```
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils

# Load training data
training = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt").toDF()

lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8)

# Fit the model
lrModel = lr.fit(training)

# Print the weights and intercept for linear regression
print("Weights: " + str(lrModel.weights))
print("Intercept: " + str(lrModel.intercept))
```

If you read into the setup, you'll find that:

> By setting `α` properly, elastic net contains both L1 and L2 regularization as special cases. For example, if a linear regression model is trained with the elastic net parameter `α` set to 1, it is equivalent to a *Lasso model*. On the other hand, if `α` is set to 0, the trained model reduces to a *ridge regression model*.

Where:

> `elasticNetParam` corresponds to `α` and `regParam` corresponds to `λ`.